# Ubuntu guest on Ubuntu IPv6 host IPv6 not responding in or out

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6

Ubuntu MATE 19.04 on VirtualBox 6.06 using bridged adapter.

IPv6 on host - yes.

IPv4 on guest - yes.

IPv6 on guest enabled - yes.

Thanks to JayEye for prompting info below:

Cannot ping IPv6 from guest while same address on host gets response.

Firewall is inactive.

**Server address**

```
inet6 2604:-:-:-::-/128 scope global 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Client address**

```
inet6 2001:aaa:bbbb:cccc:ddd:eeee:ffff:ggg/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
   valid_lft 14685sec preferred_lft 14385sec
inet6 fe80::a00:27gg:fexy:92k/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Client routes**

```
 ip -4 r
 default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.75 metric 100 
 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.75 
 192.168.1.254 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.75 metric 100 

 ip -6 r
 ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
 22001:aaa:bbbb:cccc::/64 dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 expires 14682sec pref medium
 fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
 default via fe80::-:95ff:fea3:- dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 expires 1782sec pref medium
```

**Note:** Link local of the router is the same for Host and Guest.

Comment: I assume you are trying to ping a global IP address? What does your routing table look like on the guest?

Comment: @JayEye Updated question to your suggestions.

Comment: OK, you have a default route, so that's not the problem. Is the link-local address of the default router in the host the same as in the guest (they should be if you have a bridged interface and only one exit router). Can you ping the LL address of the router from the guest? When doing so, what does tcpdump on the host tell you?

I also assume you don't have any firewall rules making your day harder than it already is :)

Comment: @JayEye So before I add to the question -- to be sure: that's the `default via fe80::-:95ff:fea3:- dev enp0s3 proto ra metric 100 expires 1782sec pref medium` item? Same on host and guest yes. Firewall is off.

Comment: yes, that's the one.